# Javascript jQuery plugin - multiple instances, external control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to wrap a canvas function in a jquery plugin, so that it can be invoked via multiple instances.

I want to be able to loop through found items and call the plugin like this

http://jsfiddle.net/M99EY/69/

HTML...

```
<div id="select1" class="foo" data-init="multi">A</div>
<div id="select2" class="foo" data-init="multi">B</div>
<div id="select3" class="foo" data-init="multi">C</div>
<div id="select4" class="foo" data-init="multi">D</div>
```

JS
...

```
var complicatedObj = {
    init: function(element){
        this.el = element;
        console.log("init method", this.el);
       //start a complicated process 
       //like rendering a canvas applicaation

        this.bindEvent();
        this.addRandom(this.el);
    },
    addRandom: function(el){
        $(el).text(Math.random());
    },
    reInit: function(){
        console.log("re-initialize method");
    },
    bindEvent: function(){
        $(this.el).click(function() {
            console.log("Letter.", $(this).text());
        });
    }
}
//An application with complicated functions -- initialize, re-initialize


$.multiInstance = {
    id: 'multiInstance',
    version: '1.0',
    defaults: { // default settings
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};

(function ($) {
    //Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({

        multiInstance: function (params) {
            //Merge default and user parameters
            var otherGeneralVars = 'example';

            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this), opts = $.extend({},$.multiInstance.defaults, params);

                switch (params) {
                    case "init":
                        complicatedObj.init($this);
                        break;
                    case "reInit":
                        complicatedObj.addRandom($this);
                        break;
                }  

                //console.log("$this", $this);


                console.log("params", params);
                //$this.text(opts.foo);
            });
        }
    })
})(jQuery);


/*
$("#select1").multiInstance();
$("#select2").multiInstance({foo:"foobar"})
$("#select3").multiInstance("init");*/

$('[data-init="multi"]').each(function( index ) {
    //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text());
    $(this).multiInstance("init");
});

setTimeout(function(){ $('#select3').multiInstance("reInit"); }, 2000);
```

but I need to be able to invoke different methods, pass arguments to these methods -- and then when a change has occurred - provide a callback to catch changes to the instance

Is this the correct way of building the plugin... I want to be able to create multiple instances of the app -- but also control it externally - and also pull values out of it for external results.

Comment: _"but also control it externally - and also pull values out of it for external result"_ Can describe "control it externally" ?

Comment: Ok - so like this plugin - is a carousel -and you have next/prev arrows bound to it... and multiple carousels . -- but there are also other control user interface components like select boxes, inputs --- that control one or two carousels (as if they were twins).  So a changed select box - invokes a change in the carousels plugin. But then I need the plugin to talk to the external realm to indicate which slide its on. Almost create a master/slave - vice versa relationship

Comment: Should I drop the "complicatedObj" and place all the functions that are inside this as part of "$.multiInstance" ? --- say also there is an img.load - or something that could take a few seconds to act on - I've found that my "carousel" -- really a canvas 360 app breaks in multiple instances

Comment: _"need the plugin to talk to the external realm to indicate which slide its on."_ Can describe "talk to the external realm"?  _"Almost create a master/slave - vice versa relationship"_ What is a _"master/slave - vice versa relationship"_ ? Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: -- external realm --- the rest of the site - if you imagine it as a massive dashboard app. "master/slave" -- I use the carousel to change to a different photograph and it toggles the other controls (inputs, slider) to match the change. I change the controls (inputs, slider) it changes the carousel

Comment: _"Is this the correct way of building the plugin..."_ Does plugin return expected results ?

Comment: Please look over the code, improve the jsfiddle. The plugin works if there is only 1 instance of it. It breaks if you try and run multiple instances... https://jsfiddle.net/mxx67b9m/9/  --- the first problem is waiting for an img.load callback

Comment: Whats is expected result at https://jsfiddle.net/mxx67b9m/9/ ?

Comment: If images could be supplied to it - it would render 2 canvas objects - in this case 2 different watches - where you would be able to revolve around them. Can we stop asking questions on this now and get some solutions going

Answer (score 0):

This is the application I am trying to wrap into its own jquery plugin.

https://jsfiddle.net/7a4738jo/10/

css..

```
body {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas{
    background: grey;
}
```

html..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas1' data-init="canvas360" width="465" height="465"></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas2' data-init="canvas360" width="465" height="465"></canvas>
```

js...

```
var stage;

function init(element) {   
    var canvas = $(element)[0];
    if (!canvas || !canvas.getContext) return;

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);  
    stage.enableMouseOver(true);
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true; 
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

    var imgList = ["http://jsrun.it/assets/N/b/D/X/NbDXj.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/f/K/7/y/fK7yE.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/U/q/d/jUqdG.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/q/o/4/j/qo4jP.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/i/Q/e/1/iQe1f.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/5/k/y/R/5kyRi.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/x/T/I/h/xTIhA.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/X/G/F/4XGFt.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/6/7/n/r/67nrO.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/k/i/r/8/kir8T.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/F/q/23Fqt.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/c/l/d/5/cld59.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/e/J/O/f/eJOf1.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/o/j/Z/x/ojZx4.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/b/g/V/4bgVf.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/m/1/8/4m18z.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/w/b/F/4wbFX.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/k/T/G/4kTGQ.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/s/n/C/r/snCrr.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/7/f/H/u/7fHuI.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/v/S/d/F/vSdFm.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/g/c/S/mgcSp.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/t/L/t/P/tLtPF.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/7/e/H/j7eHx.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/o/8/I/mo8Ij.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/n/P/7/h/nP7ht.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/z/f/K/S/zfKSP.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/4/U/234U6.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/d/Z/y/m/dZymk.jpg"];  

    var images = [], loaded = 0, currentFrame = 0, totalFrames = imgList.length; 
    var rotate360Interval, start_x;

    var bg = new createjs.Shape();
    stage.addChild(bg);  

    var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap();      
    stage.addChild(bmp);

    var myTxt = new createjs.Text("HTC One", '24px Ubuntu', "#ffffff");
    myTxt.x = myTxt.y =20;
    myTxt.alpha = 0.08;
    stage.addChild(myTxt);   


    function load360Image() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgList[loaded];
        img.onload = img360Loaded;
        images[loaded] = img;   
    }

    function img360Loaded(event) {
        loaded++;        
        bg.graphics.clear()
        bg.graphics.beginFill("#222").drawRect(0,0,stage.canvas.width * loaded/totalFrames, stage.canvas.height);
        bg.graphics.endFill();

        if(loaded==totalFrames) start360();
        else load360Image();
    }


    function start360() {
        document.body.style.cursor='none';

        // 360 icon
        var iconImage = new Image();
        iconImage.src = "http://jsrun.it/assets/y/n/D/c/ynDcT.png";
        iconImage.onload = iconLoaded;        

        // update-draw
        update360(0);

        // first rotation
        rotate360Interval = setInterval(function(){ if(currentFrame===totalFrames-1) { clearInterval(rotate360Interval); addNavigation(); } update360(1); }, 25);
    }

    function iconLoaded(event) {
        var iconBmp = new createjs.Bitmap();
        iconBmp.image = event.target;
        iconBmp.x = 20;
        iconBmp.y = canvas.height - iconBmp.image.height - 20;
        stage.addChild(iconBmp);
    }

    function update360(dir) {
        currentFrame+=dir;
        if(currentFrame<0) currentFrame = totalFrames-1;
        else if(currentFrame>totalFrames-1) currentFrame = 0;
        bmp.image = images[currentFrame];
    }


    //------------------------------- 
     function addNavigation() { 
        stage.onMouseOver = mouseOver;
        stage.onMouseDown = mousePressed;        
        document.body.style.cursor='auto';
    }

    function mouseOver(event) {
        document.body.style.cursor='pointer';
    }

    function mousePressed(event) {
        start_x = event.rawX;
        stage.onMouseMove = mouseMoved;
        stage.onMouseUp = mouseUp;

        document.body.style.cursor='w-resize';        
    }

    function mouseMoved(event) {
        var dx = event.rawX - start_x;
        var abs_dx = Math.abs(dx);

        if(abs_dx>5) {
            update360(dx/abs_dx);
            start_x = event.rawX;
        }
    }

    function mouseUp(event) {
        stage.onMouseMove = null;
        stage.onMouseUp = null;         
        document.body.style.cursor='pointer';
    }    

    function handleTick() { 
         stage.update();
    }    

    document.body.style.cursor='progress';
    load360Image();


     // TICKER
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
}




// Init
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create multiple instances of canvas
    $('[data-init="canvas360"]').each(function(index) {
      init(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is the latest application --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158503/failing-canvas-360-jquery-plugin