# Failing Canvas 360 jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jquery-plugins

This is as close as I have come..

but its breaking when loading in the images -- only the 2nd canvas appears to render?

the problem seems to occur during the img.load callback

https://jsfiddle.net/7a4738jo/24/

html..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="one" data-init="table" width="465" height="465">1</canvas>
<canvas id="two" data-init="table" width="465" height="465">2</canvas>
```

js...

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        string1: "hello ",
        string2: "world!"
    };
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            if (options) {
                $.extend(defaults, options);
            }
            //console.log("defaults", defaults);
            methods.start(this);
            //console.log(defaults.string1 + defaults.string2);
        },
        test: function (arg) {
            console.log("test: " + arg.args);
            console.log("args: " + defaults.string1 + defaults.string2);
        },
        reInit: function () {
            this.loaded = 0; //reset
            this.render();
            this.load360Image(false);
        },
        setCursor: function (cursor) {
            document.body.style.cursor = cursor;
        },
        render: function () {
            //load in a new render
            this.fileCount = this.el.data("file-count");
            this.path = this.el.data("file-path");
            this.startFrame = 10;

            //create img list
            this.imgList = [];

            /*
            for (i = 1; i <= this.fileCount; i++) {
                this.imgList.push(this.path + i + ".png");
            }*/

            this.imgList = ["http://jsrun.it/assets/N/b/D/X/NbDXj.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/f/K/7/y/fK7yE.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/U/q/d/jUqdG.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/q/o/4/j/qo4jP.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/i/Q/e/1/iQe1f.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/5/k/y/R/5kyRi.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/x/T/I/h/xTIhA.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/X/G/F/4XGFt.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/6/7/n/r/67nrO.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/k/i/r/8/kir8T.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/F/q/23Fqt.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/c/l/d/5/cld59.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/e/J/O/f/eJOf1.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/o/j/Z/x/ojZx4.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/b/g/V/4bgVf.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/m/1/8/4m18z.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/w/b/F/4wbFX.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/k/T/G/4kTGQ.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/s/n/C/r/snCrr.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/7/f/H/u/7fHuI.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/v/S/d/F/vSdFm.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/g/c/S/mgcSp.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/t/L/t/P/tLtPF.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/7/e/H/j7eHx.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/o/8/I/mo8Ij.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/n/P/7/h/nP7ht.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/z/f/K/S/zfKSP.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/4/U/234U6.jpg", 
                   "http://jsrun.it/assets/d/Z/y/m/dZymk.jpg"];


            this.totalFrames = this.imgList.length;
        },
        start: function (element) {
            var self = this;
            console.log(">>>element",element);
            this.el = element;

            this.canvas = this.el[0];
            if (!this.canvas || !this.canvas.getContext) {
                return;
            }
            console.log(">>>methods.canvas",this.canvas);

            this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
            this.stage.enableMouseOver(true);
            this.stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
            createjs.Touch.enable(methods.stage);

            this.images = [];
            this.loaded = 0;
            this.currentFrame = 0
            this.rotate360Interval;
            this.start_x;

            this.bg = new createjs.Shape();
            this.stage.addChild(this.bg);

            this.bmp = new createjs.Bitmap();
            this.stage.addChild(this.bmp);

            var myTxt = new createjs.Text("HTC One", '24px Ubuntu', "#ffffff");
            myTxt.x = myTxt.y = 20;
            myTxt.alpha = 0.08;
            this.stage.addChild(myTxt);

            this.setCursor("progress");

            this.render();
            //console.log(this.el[0]);
            this.load360Image(true);

            // TICKER
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function (event) {
                self.stage.update();
            });
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
            createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;

            return this.canvas;
        },
        load360Image: function (spin) {
            var img = new Image();
            //img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

            img.src = this.imgList[this.loaded];

            this.img360Loaded(img, spin);
            this.images[this.loaded] = img;
        },
        img360Loaded: function (img, spin) {
            //console.log("LOAD IMG", this.el[0], img);
            var that = this;
            img.onload = function (event) {
                //console.log(img);

                that.loaded++;
                that.bg.graphics.clear()
                that.bg.graphics.beginFill("#222").drawRect(0, 0, that.stage.canvas.width * that.loaded / that.totalFrames, that.stage.canvas.height);
                that.bg.graphics.endFill();


                if (that.loaded == that.totalFrames) {
                    that.start360(spin);
                } else {
                    that.load360Image(spin);
                }

                //console.log(">>LOAD IMG DONE", that.el[0]);
            }
        },
        start360: function (spin) {
            this.setCursor("none");

            // 360 icon
            var iconImage = new Image();
            //iconImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            iconImage.src = this.el.data("icon-path") + "360.png";
            this.iconLoaded(iconImage);

            // update-draw
            this.update360(0);

            if (spin) {
                this.revolveOnce(function () {
                    //console.log("done");
                }, 25);
            }
            this.setCursor("auto");
        },
        revolveOnce: function (callback, speed) {
            var self = this;
            // first rotation
            this.rotate360Interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (self.currentFrame === self.totalFrames - 1) {
                    clearInterval(self.rotate360Interval);
                    self.addNavigation();
                }
                self.update360(1);

                if (self.currentFrame === self.totalFrames - 1) {
                    callback();
                }
            }, speed);
        },
        iconLoaded: function (iconImage) {
            var self = this;
            iconImage.onload = function (event) {
                var iconBmp = new createjs.Bitmap();
                iconBmp.image = event.target;
                iconBmp.x = 20;
                iconBmp.y = self.canvas.height - iconBmp.image.height - 70;
                self.stage.addChild(iconBmp);
            }
        },
        setFrame: function (newFrame) {
            this.bmp.image = this.images[newFrame];
        },
        addNavigation: function () {

            var self = this;

            this.stage.onMouseOver = function (event) {
                self.setCursor("pointer");
            }

            this.stage.onMouseDown = function (event) {
                self.start_x = event.rawX;
                self.stage.onMouseMove = self.mouseMoved;

                self.stage.onMouseMove = function (event) {
                    var dx = event.rawX - self.start_x;
                    var abs_dx = Math.abs(dx);

                    if (abs_dx > 5) {
                        self.update360(dx / abs_dx);
                        self.start_x = event.rawX;
                    }
                }

                self.stage.onMouseUp = function (event) {
                    self.stage.onMouseMove = null;
                    self.stage.onMouseUp = null;
                    self.setCursor("pointer");
                    core.changeOnStage(this, self.currentFrame);
                }

                self.setCursor("w-resize");
            }


            this.setCursor("auto");
        },
        update360: function (dir) {
            this.currentFrame += dir;

            if (this.currentFrame < 0) {
                this.currentFrame = this.totalFrames - 1;
            } else if (this.currentFrame > this.totalFrames - 1) {
                this.currentFrame = 0;
            }
            this.bmp.image = this.images[this.currentFrame];
        }
    };
    $.fn.dataTable = function (method) {
        var args = arguments;
        var $this = this;
        return this.each(function () {
            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 0));
            } else {
                $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin');
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery);


// Init
$(document).ready(function () {
    //create multiple instances of canvas
    $('[data-init="table"]').each(function (index) {
        var instance = $(this).dataTable();
        console.log("instance", instance);
    });

    $("#two").dataTable("test", {
        args: "test args passed"
    });
});
```

Comment: Any suggestions - changes - its urgent to fix this problem

Comment: This is urgent ---- why does it fail to load more than once instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `plugin` approach, you could make it a `widget`. You wouldn't need too much changes and it would be more flexible. See here, with almost no change to your code:

```
 $(function () {

    $.widget("custom.threesixty", {
        // default options
        options: {

        },

        // the constructor
        _create: function () {
            this.start(this.element);
        },


        _refresh: function () {

        },


        // events bound via _on are removed automatically
        // revert other modifications here
        _destroy: function () {

        },

        // _setOptions is called with a hash of all options that are changing
        // always refresh when changing options
        _setOptions: function () {
            // _super and _superApply handle keeping the right this-context
            this._superApply(arguments);
            this._refresh();
        },

        // _setOption is called for each individual option that is changing
        _setOption: function (key, value) {

            this._super(key, value);
        },
        setCursor: function (cursor) {
            document.body.style.cursor = cursor;
        },
        render: function () {
            //load in a new render
            this.fileCount = this.el.data("file-count");
            this.path = this.el.data("file-path");
            this.startFrame = 10;

            //create img list
            this.imgList = [];

            /*
            for (i = 1; i <= this.fileCount; i++) {
                this.imgList.push(this.path + i + ".png");
            }*/

            this.imgList = ["http://jsrun.it/assets/N/b/D/X/NbDXj.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/f/K/7/y/fK7yE.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/U/q/d/jUqdG.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/q/o/4/j/qo4jP.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/i/Q/e/1/iQe1f.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/5/k/y/R/5kyRi.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/x/T/I/h/xTIhA.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/X/G/F/4XGFt.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/6/7/n/r/67nrO.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/k/i/r/8/kir8T.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/F/q/23Fqt.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/c/l/d/5/cld59.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/e/J/O/f/eJOf1.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/o/j/Z/x/ojZx4.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/w/K/2/m/wK2m3.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/b/g/V/4bgVf.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/m/1/8/4m18z.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/w/b/F/4wbFX.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/4/k/T/G/4kTGQ.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/s/n/C/r/snCrr.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/7/f/H/u/7fHuI.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/v/S/d/F/vSdFm.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/g/c/S/mgcSp.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/t/L/t/P/tLtPF.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/j/7/e/H/j7eHx.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/m/o/8/I/mo8Ij.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/n/P/7/h/nP7ht.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/z/f/K/S/zfKSP.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/2/3/4/U/234U6.jpg",
                "http://jsrun.it/assets/d/Z/y/m/dZymk.jpg"];


            this.totalFrames = this.imgList.length;
        },
        reInit: function () {
            this.loaded = 0; //reset
            this.render();
            this.load360Image(false);
        },
        start: function (element) {
            var self = this;
            console.log(">>>element", element);
            this.el = element;

            this.canvas = this.el[0];
            if (!this.canvas || !this.canvas.getContext) {
                return;
            }
            console.log(">>>methods.canvas", this.canvas);

            this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
            this.stage.enableMouseOver(true);
            this.stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
            createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);

            this.images = [];
            this.loaded = 0;
            this.currentFrame = 0
            this.rotate360Interval;
            this.start_x;

            this.bg = new createjs.Shape();
            this.stage.addChild(this.bg);

            this.bmp = new createjs.Bitmap();
            this.stage.addChild(this.bmp);

            var myTxt = new createjs.Text("HTC One", '24px Ubuntu', "#ffffff");
            myTxt.x = myTxt.y = 20;
            myTxt.alpha = 0.08;
            this.stage.addChild(myTxt);

            this.setCursor("progress");

            this.render();
            //console.log(this.el[0]);
            this.load360Image(true);

            // TICKER
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function (event) {
                self.stage.update();
            });
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
            createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;

            return this.canvas;
        },
        load360Image: function (spin) {
            var img = new Image();
            //img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

            img.src = this.imgList[this.loaded];

            this.img360Loaded(img, spin);
            this.images[this.loaded] = img;
        },
        img360Loaded: function (img, spin) {
            console.log("LOAD IMG", this.el[0], img);
            var that = this;
            img.onload = function (event) {
                //console.log(img);

                that.loaded++;
                that.bg.graphics.clear()
                that.bg.graphics.beginFill("#222").drawRect(0, 0, that.stage.canvas.width * that.loaded / that.totalFrames, that.stage.canvas.height);
                that.bg.graphics.endFill();


                if (that.loaded == that.totalFrames) {
                    that.start360(spin);
                } else {
                    that.load360Image(spin);
                }

                //console.log(">>LOAD IMG DONE", that.el[0]);
            }
        },
        start360: function (spin) {
            this.setCursor("none");

            // 360 icon
            var iconImage = new Image();
            //iconImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            iconImage.src = this.el.data("icon-path") + "360.png";
            this.iconLoaded(iconImage);

            // update-draw
            this.update360(0);

            if (spin) {
                this.revolveOnce(function () {
                    //console.log("done");
                }, 25);
            }
            this.setCursor("auto");
        },
        revolveOnce: function (callback, speed) {
            var self = this;
            // first rotation
            self.rotate360Interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (self.currentFrame === self.totalFrames - 1) {
                    clearInterval(self.rotate360Interval);
                    self.addNavigation();
                }
                self.update360(1);

                if (self.currentFrame === self.totalFrames - 1) {
                    callback();
                }
            }, speed);
        },
        iconLoaded: function (iconImage) {
            var self = this;
            iconImage.onload = function (event) {
                var iconBmp = new createjs.Bitmap();
                iconBmp.image = event.target;
                iconBmp.x = 20;
                iconBmp.y = self.canvas.height - iconBmp.image.height - 70;
                self.stage.addChild(iconBmp);
            }
        },
        setFrame: function (newFrame) {
            this.bmp.image = this.images[newFrame];
        },
        addNavigation: function () {

            var self = this;

            self.stage.onMouseOver = function (event) {
                self.setCursor("pointer");
            }

            self.stage.onMouseDown = function (event) {
                self.start_x = event.rawX;
                self.stage.onMouseMove = self.mouseMoved;

                self.stage.onMouseMove = function (event) {
                    var dx = event.rawX - self.start_x;
                    var abs_dx = Math.abs(dx);

                    if (abs_dx > 5) {
                        self.update360(dx / abs_dx);
                        self.start_x = event.rawX;
                    }
                }

                self.stage.onMouseUp = function (event) {
                    self.stage.onMouseMove = null;
                    self.stage.onMouseUp = null;
                    self.setCursor("pointer");
                    self.changeOnStage(this, self.currentFrame);
                }

                self.setCursor("w-resize");
            }


            this.setCursor("auto");
        },
        update360: function (dir) {
            this.currentFrame += dir;

            if (this.currentFrame < 0) {
                this.currentFrame = this.totalFrames - 1;
            } else if (this.currentFrame > this.totalFrames - 1) {
                this.currentFrame = 0;
            }
            this.bmp.image = this.images[this.currentFrame];
        }
    });
    $('[data-init="table"]').threesixty()
    $("#trigger").click(function () {
        console.log("try other method");
        $("#two").data("file-path", "mobile4").data("file-count", 20);
        $("#two").threesixty("reInit");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4vLyt5n/7/

This gives you access to generic methods of jQuery-ui such as destroy, set options, etc. See doc here: https://jqueryui.com/widget/

Basically, you call methods like this:

```
$(element).threesixty(method, args)
```

So you can do something like this:

```
$(element).threesixty('instance')//to access the instance
$(element).threesixty('start')//to call start method
$(element).threesixty('option', key, value)//to set options one it's instantiated
$(element).threesixty({
    option1: value,
    option2: value,
});//to set options when creating it
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is because on each call, you are redefining the same object, which gets the first canvas assigned on first call, then it is changed to the second one on second call.

What you need is to reformat your code so that each time you call the `methods.init`, it creates a new object.

In this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a4738jo/27/), you'll find a quick and dirty way, just to illustrate this.

Comment: I have a few external functions - that would get called by the plugin - but they break now with the way the code has been refactored. Specifically when the reInit is invokved -- when it comes to render - the code can no longer cipher off the data attributes of the selector.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7a4738jo/40/ -- if I need to change a path I used the reInits method -- but this breaks now with the new implementations you made... I tried setting the new this.el =that -- but it leads me down a rabbit hole - whats going on... I just need reInits to pick up a new image path --- and then reinitialise the application

Comment: As I told you, It's quick and dirty. IMO, your code would need a serious cleanup. For this particular problem, it's because my implementation did create a new instance of the object on each call. What you want is to attach a new instance and then reuse it on each call. You can e.g attach it to your canvases in the calling part : `$this[0].__superView = $this[0].__superView || new methods($this); var meth = $this[0].__superView;`. But you could also store those objects in a global array or anywhere you want. See [update](https://jsfiddle.net/7a4738jo/41/)

Comment: There is a bounty out to do the major clearup as you mentioned